# Pattern For .NET Regex Replace Method

Tags: .net, regex

I want to use the .NET Regex Replace method to separate numbers in a string.

String:`"Delivery order #135670 is ready for pick up."`

Replacement String:`"Delivery order # 1 3 5 6 7 0 is ready for pick up."`

This is as far as I've gotten.

Matching Pattern:`((?<=\#)\d+)`

I think this means: If a hash sign is the previous character, match one or more decimal digits. This pattern can be matched one time.

I have no idea how to do the replacement pattern.

If this seems to you like an odd thing to do, it's a way to get a speech synthesizer to speak "number one three five six seven zero" instead of "number one hundred thirty five thousand six hundred seventy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your help. After reading the advice of Bas, zx81 and Avinash I put together the following, which is being used successfully in the application.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\d|#)");
message = regex.Replace(message, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `MatchEvaluator` (lambda) to add spaces:

```
string value = "Delivery order #135670 is ready for pick up.";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(#\d+)");
string result = r.Replace(value, m => string.Join(" ", 
                          m.Captures[0].Value.ToCharArray()));
//result = "Delivery order # 1 3 5 6 7 0 is ready for pick up.";
```

The regex `(#\d+)` does the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern and in the replacement part, replace the matched ones  with a space  character.

```
(?<=\d|#)(?! )
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zQ9qV5/4)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one-liner you're looking for:

```
String replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?=\d)", " ");
```

In the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/12), look at the substitutions pane at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- The regex matches a position, not characters. This is called a zero-width match.
- The lookahead `(?=\d)` asserts that what follows is a digit. If you want to be exact about it, you could use `(?=\[0-9])` as .NET `\d` also matches Thai digits and so on, but that doesn't seem like a big risk here
- We replace with a space.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)